# Calculation between 2 dates in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using the script below to count a number of days between 2 dates in my form.

I have a condition says if start date is greater than end date, count day=0

I would like to add: else if ($endDate-$startDate<7){ $day_count = 8;}

But I always have an error.

Could you please help?

Thank you

Original code :

```
 function override_submitted_value( $form ) {

    $start_date = false;
    $end_date = false;

    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if( $field['id'] == $this->start_field_id )
            $start_date = self::parse_field_date( $field );

        if( $field['id'] == $this->end_field_id )
            $end_date = self::parse_field_date( $field );

    }

    if( $start_date > $end_date ) {

        $day_count = 0;

    } else {

        $diff = $end_date - $start_date;
        $day_count = $diff / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ); // secs * mins * hours
        $day_count = round( $day_count ) + $this->count_adjust;

    }

    $_POST["input_{$this->count_field_id}"] = $day_count;

}
```

Comment: This is not javascript for a start. And what's "the error" ?

Comment: what's stopping you from adding the statement? Beside this, it seems your  ($endDate-$startDate<7){ $day_count = 8;} looks slightly odd,

Comment: What are the `$*_date` values? timestamps? strings?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
function override_submitted_value( $form ) {

    $start_date = false;
    $end_date = false;

    foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {

        if( $field['id'] == $this->start_field_id )
            $start_date = new DateTime( $field );

        if( $field['id'] == $this->end_field_id )
            $end_date = new DateTime( $field );

    }

    $interval = $start_date->diff($end_date);
    $day_count = ($start_date > $end_date ? 0 : $interval->format('%a'));

    $_POST["input_{$this->count_field_id}"] = $day_count;

}
```

Comment: Thank you corax228. How to do you think I can add a condition says If $interval is < 8 so $day_count = 7 and if $interval is > 7 so $day_count = $interval